# Broken images on election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, election

There are broken images on election page of any SE site, e.g. on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/election/):

> [image: SO]

As suggested by PeterJ in [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323891/broken-images-on-election-page#comment1058605_323891) opening the flair image leads to HTTP 500 error. Screenshot from the Chrome browser:

> [image: Chrome 500]

Comment: Works here, Windows 10, Firefox 65.0

Comment: @Jenayah hmm ... looks fine with VPN too. Seems the Russian roskomnadzor issue

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, seem roskomnadzor not like αλεχολυτ :-D all works

Comment: Looks like an HTTP error 500 retrieving the flair icons: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/34397.png

Comment: @PeterJ That link loads absolutely fine for me. Could be a geography-specific issue.

Comment: A similar issue with flair was pointed out in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7551414#7551414) yesterday. Personally, I can't reproduce either, but unless rene can see flairs now, it excludes geography-specific as rene and I are from the same small country.

Comment: No repro here, maybe related to Teams? Try to copy and paste URL of a broken image if it's still broken.

Comment: MSO report: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380133/578411

Comment: @Tinkeringbell using the different ISP also solve the issue. For instance, works on my phone via mobile network, and broken for my office ISP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We had a web server that was misbehaving in ways that really don't make any sense, and as part of a debug of things, a reboot magically fixed it. System.Drawing (being swapped soon) was saving 0 byte files *only on this box* (`ny-web05`). This meant all users had a 1 in 9 chance of hitting the issue, for all flair from the box. Unfortunately `System.Drawing` throws an `OutOfMemory` exception for *everything* and is damn near useless in terms of debugging anything after-the-fact.

Since we're going to replace all this code for the .NET Core port here, I'm not advising we spend any more time digging into it...it's just not a good use of resources.

TL;DR: I know *what* it was doing, but not *why* it was doing it. And the symptoms are no longer there to debug. So we'll call this a fluke.

Comment: You happily ignored the warning in the [remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=netframework-4.7.2) *Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.*  ;)  thanks for the fix, you rock!

Comment: @rene yeah, but it worked for 9 years so...

Comment: Such a great and complex system and a simple reboot fixes all the problems... ;)

Comment: I seem to be hitting this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366787/165261); is it possible that this issue has cropped back up?

Comment: For all flair themes (Default, Clean, Dark, Hotdog) images are not displayed. The console is showing an error as `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`. Is it possible that this is the cause for this?