# Flair images are throwing 500 errors for some percentage of users, affecting election pages particularly badly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flair, 500-server-error

For me, the election pages on all the sites currently look something like this:

[image: screenshot of election page with broken images instead of user flair]

Examples: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election/), [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/election/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/election)

And my Stack Overflow profile flair page looks like this (note that there should be five flair images, but four are replaced with their alt text):
[image: screenshot of profile flair page with alt text instead of user flair]

Most people appear unable to reproduce this, but [at least one other person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366787/the-election-page-is-showing-broken-images-instead-of-the-elected-users-flair#comment1222293_366787) has confirmed in the comments that they can also reproduce it.  This resembles [a previous issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323895/165261) (marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) in which 1 in 9 users would see similar errors.

Could this be fixed?

Comment: Status-norepro for me

Comment: [They all look fine to me](https://i.imgur.com/2YtkgPk.png). Try to disable extensions/userscripts.

Comment: It's reliably reproducing for me across multiple browsers and computers, including without extensions.

Comment: @RyanM As with the other 2 commenters, all 3 linked pages display properly for me as well.

Comment: @RyanM I would next check network/VPN.

Comment: The issue that I'm seeing is that the images are linked with the wrong URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/366904.png instead of https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/366904.png, for instance.

Comment: @RyanM can you also reproduce on a mobile device on a cellular signal?

Comment: @RyanM your first linked image works, the second does not.

Comment: On mobile: If I load the page for the first time on cellular, it works, even after switching to Wi-Fi.  If I load the page for the first time on Wi-Fi, it breaks, even after switching to cellular.

Comment: @RyanM when you browse directly to such a URL (of a broken image) what you see? You get some Internal Server Error? If so, try to load elections page while logged out, or Incognito mode, and see if it loads fine.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I browse directly to the image URL, but it works in incognito mode.

Comment: I think a mistake on mobile testing was that I used one signed-in and one signed-out browser.  It is indeed broken on a cell connection, but only when I'm logged in...and seemingly only when I start on Wi-Fi.  Bizarre.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323895/165261 - would explain why I can see it and seemingly no one else can.

Comment: For me, the images are also broken.

Comment: The images are broken for me as well.

Comment: In Ask Ubuntu: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19637

Comment: Can anyone still repro this?

Answer (score 3):

Marking this as norepro, as it looks like the problem has resolved on its own (caching issue? errant server rebuilt?). If anyone sees this again, please let me know.

Comment: I'm experiencing this again - happened to glance at my profile and my flair is borked.

Comment: Same here: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1540386.png only gives me an Ooops. Also just spotted this now when looking at my profile. Seems to be the global one that is still broken.

Comment: Looks like it happens [to another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368165/combined-profiles-flair-image-is-not-found).