# Provide image alt text for the flair images on the /election page

Tags: feature-request, images, election, flair, accessibility

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366787/the-election-page-is-showing-broken-images-instead-of-the-elected-users-flair).

---

Currently the user flair on the /election [[SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/election/) page has no Alt-atribute. This makes it hard to see which users won an election when images can't be viewed for whatever reason, server outages or people that are visually impaired.

On one's own flair page: `/users/[uid]/[uname]/flair` the images have a proper title and alt atribute. Mine are:

```
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1481116.png" alt="profile for Luuklag at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for Luuklag at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" width="208" height="58">
```

Can this please be used on the election page as well?

Comment: Or maybe display the user card instead of the flair image? Why does it have to be an image in the first place?

Comment: @41686d6564 dunno why, but I do like it, it feels more "clean" for me. I want it to still be this way, however without alt text it's against all modern accessibility rules and standards, which is a shame, even if ancient overlook.

Comment: Also worth to mention, even maybe in the request itself, that the page [does not pass validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Felection%2F), with clear errors: *An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions*.