# Attempting to load combined flair images sometimes, but not always, results in a server error

Tags: bug, status-deferred, flair, 500-server-error, combined-flair

I display my combined flair on my profile page. But I noticed that it's broken. When I go to profile setting -> flair I see that all my flairs work other than the combined flair.

Here is my combined flair:

[image]

1. Meta flair setting page.

[image]

2. Stack Overflow flair setting page.

[image]

My current profile:

[image]

When I visit the image page directly for the combined flair, it gives an error:

[image]

If it matters:

Browser: Chrome Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What you get when you browse directly [to your flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/411877.png)? (I see it just fine)

Comment: ohh.. most likely [this no repro bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366787/flair-images-are-throwing-500-errors-for-some-percentage-of-users-affecting-ele)

Comment: If you can use VPN give this a try, good chance that you'll get to see your flair just fine.

Comment: Now also reported on MSO: [Combined flair does not show](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410545/4642212).

Comment: I ran into this a few days ago, it was 404 at the time, but when I checked back a few hours later it remediated itself. Maybe some space particles went through SE's datacenter and caused some transient bug?

Comment: Likely *not* a CDN issue, we did some initial investigation today and narrowed it down to an exception on a minority of our servers. We were able to reproduce the problem but we don't have an estimate on a fix yet.

Comment: any news? I still don't see combined flairs...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Same here . Bug is not resolved yet.

Comment: [My flair died](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/7886663.png) if anyone wants to investigate. It's an intermittent issue.

Comment: Any ETA? Its been 7 days without news about this...

Comment: Was this forgotten? It's been almost 2 weeks without news...

Comment: Yep - in fact, it was forgotten. The month is ending and no updates regarding this issue.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado it could help to ping certain people ;)

Comment: @KylePollard is there anything you can share on this issue with us?

Comment: @Leonardo I hear your worries and I'm sorry that it hasn't been fixed yet. It's going to require a deeper dive to resolve, we didn't get an easy fix out of our original investigation.  I don't have a timeline to share right now, but I can assure you that it's been on our team's bug backlog and won't be forgotten 

Comment: It seems to be solved - at least for me :) thanks StackExchange team.

Comment: Mine died today - https://stackexchange.com/users/33230/sathyajith-bhat?tab=flair // direct link gives a 500 - something bad happened https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/33230.png

Comment: I can't see mine, or anyone's "combined flair" - unless I use an external service/VPN. I think it's perhaps a locale/CDN issue (again). I say "anyone" - I think it depends _where_ it is included?! I can see the flair on this page, but I can't see it in anyone's profile page - just a dead link (500 response).

Comment: @KylePollard the issue still seems to be around. Any guesses on when this might get fixed?

Comment: Problem is back to me again today :(

Comment: Mine stopped working too. I'm moving to this in the meantime: [**app - se-flair: HTML combined Stack Exchange site flair - Stack Apps**](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair)

Comment: Mine isn't working as well...

Comment: The Flair is not working for me too. Also, noticed that the flair for the other people's profiles is also not working.

Comment: I hope you didn't close this issue yet - it is back in my profile @KylePollard... I wonder if this is due to some cache failure policy (that is failing to get information when there is a cache miss) - it was fixed last month to me, but now it is back once again...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado still not fixed but still in our backlog, I believe it only breaks on some of our webservers so it'll work intermittently depending on which one you get

Comment: @KylePollard any update half a year later?

Comment: Hi @Luuklag, I'm a new Product Manager on the team and spent some time reading through the post to understand the issue. The ticket is still in backlog but we currently do not have an ETA. In order to accurately reflect the current status of the post, I will be updating the tag to [tag:status-deferred] for now as it requires further investigation into the minority of our servers that this affects. This issue currently does not currently fit within a larger initiative that we are working on but we will provide an update once it has been prioritized. Thank you.

Comment: @tanj92 Thanks for the response, and glad to have you on the team! It's nice for staff to be more responsive to requests here on Meta, even if those aren't always positive responses: that there's a response means a lot.

Comment: You're welcome @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog. I appreciate your understanding and thank you for your continued patience.

Comment: Do you guys at least know what is the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Mine also is not working it seems.  I noticed yesterday on my [Arqade profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/163757/timmy-jim?tab=profile) that it was not rendering (fixed now with my band-aid fix mentioned below).

I did notice just now however that if I take the link and upload it as you would when posting images on a post, it seems to pull it down just fine.

My flair's .png link "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/8729580.png" does not render an image, but after uploading it via link it does:

[image]

Of course, it doesn't properly navigate you to my SE user profile since the link behind the image is for the image itself.

[peterh's](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1988549.png) .png link does not work for me either, but again, uploading it does.

[image]

To top it all off, [Luuklag's](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1599858.png) .png like works for me.

So a (temporary?) fix for this would be to take your .png's link and upload it to i.stack.imgur and then change your flair `img src`

```html
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/8729580/timothy-g">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/M02q6.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Timothy G. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Timothy G. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" />
</a>
```

I think though the only drawback to this is the image won't get updated as your reputation changes.

Comment: You can do this in Markdown too, if you prefer: `[![Profile for Timothy G. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M02q6.png)](https://stackexchange.com/users/8729580/timothy-g "Profile for Timothy G. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites")`. You can add title/ hover text to any image by adding quoted text after the URL (`[alt text](link "title text")`).

Comment: I'm currently having this same issue (since yesterday?), however, trying to "upload" the image link does not work for me. I just get "Failed to upload image; an error occured[sic] on the server". Requesting this image results in a 500 response.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't understand from the descriptions in this thread, when I first read it, that the flair not rendering could also happen in the body of posts. But now it happened to me that on the same page half the flairs render and the other half doesn't. Screenshot take from [The Community Teams @ Stack Exchange and how we work together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together).

[image: screenshot of a post where half the flairs don't render]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 94.0.1 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2021.11.16.40766.

Comment: Strange indeed. For me they all show up in the post. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @Luuklag yes it gives the same 500 errors already mentioned in the other answer and comments for the individual flair URLs that aren't working.

Comment: [Here is how that link looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUg4o.png).  A few are broken images.

Answer (score 3):

Mine appears to work:

[image: profile for Luuklag on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: To me that shows the expected image @Shree

Comment: I update question :) refresh page, reboot pc , log out / log in, still same :(

Comment: @Shree it's not you, or your PC, or your browser - something is broken on SE side.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 works for me across computers/phones and across browsers. Probably a location specific CDN issue again then?

Comment: @Luuklag yup, most likely.

Answer (score 3):

Mine does not work. [Here is a direct link to it.](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1988549.png)

Possibly it is generated on request, and it is cached (both in the server and in the browsers). Until it does not expire from both caches, it seems working. The flair of the other answerer (@Luuklag) is working.

Extension: it gives 500 to my Firefox, but it works well with a `wget`.

Extension #2: by replicating the 'Cookie:' header of my Firefox to the `wget`, it gives 500. Very likely it does not work only with a working login. It also works from a private browser window.

Comment: For me yours works

Comment: @Luuklag Funny. To me it gives 500 to my firefox, but I still can download it with a `wget`.