# Server error when attempting to load network flairs for some users

Tags: bug, flair, 500-server-error, combined-flair

In the [list of employees on the community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349266/377214), the network flairs for some (but not all) employees aren't loading, and instead showing a broken image with alternate text.

When I attempt to manually go to the network flair for those users ([here's an example](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/20728780.png)), I get a server error page.

What's causing these server errors, and can these please be fixed?

I saw a previous report with [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371948/377214) indicating a past occurrence of this problem, but I vaguely recall reading the above post in question and being able to see it just fine a couple months after that. This seems to be a new regression of that.

Comment: A fix was never deployed for that bug report. It is [still in the backlog as of January](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368165/combined-profiles-flair-image-is-not-found/371948#comment1249369_368165) awaiting a fix.